# Sequential prediction/modeling without stationarity assumptions

Tags: forecasting, modeling, stationarity, robust, sequential-pattern-mining

Let's say that we have an arbitrary real-valued sequence of length $n$:
$$(x_{i})_{i \in \{0, \dots, n-1\}}.$$

If we wanted to try to create a probabilistic model for future values of the sequence conditional on previous observed values or, before this, even just try to learn about the dependence structure among previous and future values (if there even is any), what can we do without assuming stationarity of the process that generated the data?

As in, is there a way "outside" the concepts of stationarity/non-stationarity that we can create some sort of useful/practical predictive model such as:
$$x_i = m(x_{i-1}) + \epsilon_i$$
(where $m$ is some arbitrary function that we want to find the form of and the $e_i$'s are random error terms) or even determine if such a model is suitable in the first place (e.g. if we need to include more lags of $x_i$ or if these lags even help our model)?

Comment: Hi: any kalman filter or kalman filter variant allows for non-stationarity but I strongly suggest understanding the KF to a decent extent before attempting to use it. The literature is quite enormous so I wouldn't know what to recommend as far as material-references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need stationarity but you need *some* relationship between the values in the sequence so that the relationship can be extrapolated into the future. E.g. if all elements (random variables) in your sequence have the same expected value, then you could use the sample mean as an estimate of the future expected values. You could add a deterministic component to that, e.g. a linear time trend, and then the same would apply for detrended data, so again you could use this for prediction. Or if you are facing absolute loss instead of square loss, it would be enough that all elements in your sequence have the same median.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly the OP means by *a way*, but my answer focuses on explaining how you can forecast without stationarity.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the detailed response. I was a bit vague with "way" since I wasn't quite sure what exactly I was looking for. In trying to determine what relationship there is between the values in the sequence (if any), are there any methods we can use similar to auto-correlation or auto-mutual information that work with the values not being assumed to come from a stationary process? (Re:  concerns of spurious correlation, spurious regression, etc.)

Comment: @QMath, under some deviations from stationarity the usual methods (such as autocorrelation) should retain some value. E.g. if odd observations have variance $\sigma^2$ while even ones have variance $2\sigma^2$, I think autocorrelation might still be informative (though I have not tried it, so this is just a speculation). Other than that, I am not sure.

Comment: That makes sense and thank you for the insight! Just to make sure I am on the right path, am I correct in saying that even if our data doesn't look approximately stationary (e.g. from ADF and/or other methods), there is no problem with plotting $x_{t-1}$ against $x_t$ to attempt to deduce a relationship, but that if we are supposing a linear model (e.g., $x_t = \alpha x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$), we would run into problems trying to estimate $\alpha$ with OLS if alpha is in fact equal to or greater than 1 due to OLS assumptions being violated? (in short, that the method of parameter estimation...

Comment: ...is the problem and not our choice of model?)

Comment: @QMath, that can be the case. Your original question is more general than that, so it is hard to say much that is definite and is still useful.

Comment: Fair point and thank you very much for all the insight on this! :)